# tkinter: scrollbar isn't working on canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to code for a scrollbar that I can use to view the contents of my canvas. So, after many errors I got the scrollbar to stay in the place that it was scrolled to but it continued displaying the contents on topmost part of the window even when I scrolled down, and I saw many such similar questions and articles on how scrollbars work on canvases but nothing worked for me.

I also tried using the bbox("all") for setting the scrollregion for the canvas but that didn't work either. Using a frame didn't work either. On some similar questions, I saw that placement should be in a particular way but I didn't get how to do that or even if my code doesn't work because of that. I made the widgets as given in the canvas. I saw that at many places the same was done using the canvas.create_window command but I didn't quite understand how to use that and it worked fine without that so I didn't bother.

I have used label, entry, radiobutton, optionmenu and button in the canvas. Here's how I used the bbox("all"), which also didn't work for me and ended up the disabling the scrollbar. I have made it as short as possible.

```
    from tkinter import *
    w = Tk()
    w.geometry('650x640')

    state=StringVar()

    c=Canvas(w,bg="gray94",height=750,width=650)
    c.config(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))
    c.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

    scr=Scrollbar(c)
    scr.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

    c.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
    scr.config(command=c.yview)

    #widgets
    Button(c, text="Back").place(x=100,y=200)
    Label(c, text="Registration form",width=20,font=("bold",      
    20)).place(x=160,y=750)
    Label(c, text="State",width=20,font=("bold", 10)).place(x=149,y=390)
    l2 = ['KA','NY']
    dl2=OptionMenu(w,state, *l2)
    dl2.place(x=310,y=390)
    Button(c, text='Submit',width=20).place(x=240,y=690)

    w.mainloop()
```

And here's how it looked on execution for me.

[tkinterwindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKEVH.png)

And if I used the coordinates for scrollregion I can scroll down as shown but I still can't see the Label at y=750

[withoutbbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzVPj.png)

I'm using python 3.6.8. This is my first question, I'm sorry for any mistakes and please tell me if any information is missing or I should update the question with my full code.
Thank you :)

Comment: Set scrollbar orient and command when you are going to create a scrollbar widget. Write `scr = Scrollbar(c,orient = "vertical",command = c.yview)`.

Comment: You need to configure the scrollregion, typically with `bbox("all")`. If you say it didn't work, please show what you've tried by creating a [mcve] which also shows examples of the types of things you are adding to the canvas and how you are adding them.

Comment: @BryanOakley using bbox("all") actually just disables the scrollbar. I have also updated my question I hope this is what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas will only scroll objects that are canvas objects. You're adding the buttons and labels with `place`, which means they are *not* canvas objects. To add them to the canvas so that they will scroll you must use `c.create_window(...)`

When do configure the `scrollregion` with `c.bbox("all")` the returned bounding box is `None` because it doesn't see any items on the canvas. Thus, the scrollbars become disabled.

Typically, if you are trying to create a scrollable set of widgets, you'll pack or grid them in a frame, then add the frame to the canvas with `create_window`. There are several examples on stackoverflow for how to do this.  However, since your original code is using `place`, you can use `create_window` for each widget, using the same x/y coordinates you're using with `place`.

Here is your code, modified to use `create_window`. I've adjusted the size of the main window to show that the scrollbars work.

```
from tkinter import *
w = Tk()
w.geometry('650x400')

state=StringVar()

c=Canvas(w,bg="gray94",height=750,width=650)
c.config(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))
c.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

scr=Scrollbar(c)
scr.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

c.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
scr.config(command=c.yview)

l2 = ['KA', 'NY']

#widgets
button1 = Button(c, text="Back")
label1 = Label(c, text="Registration form", width=20, font=("bold", 20))
label2 = Label(c, text="State", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
dl2 = OptionMenu(w, state, *l2)
button2 = Button(c, text='Submit', width=20)

c.create_window(100, 200, window=button1)
c.create_window(160, 750, window=label1)
c.create_window(310, 390, window=dl2)
c.create_window(149, 390, window=label2)
c.create_window(240, 690, window=button2)

c.configure(scrollregio=c.bbox("all"))

w.mainloop()
```