# Python tkinter change Canvas height

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How do you change a canvas' height, after a widget has been added to it? I want to limit the height of a canvas, so that I can scroll it.

Here is demo code showing the problem:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=100, height=100)
canvas.grid()

tk.Label(canvas, text="TestLabel").grid()

canvas.configure(height=200)
window.update()
print(canvas.winfo_height())    # -> 21, neither 100 nor 200

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665113/tkinter-scrollbar-isnt-working-on-canvas. « To add them to the canvas so that they will scroll you must use c.create_window(...)».

Comment: Putting widget into another widget using `pack()` or `grid()` will adjust the parent widget size by default.

Comment: What is your intention with this code? Items  added inside a canvas with `pack`, `place`, or `grid` won't be scrollable and you can't use other canvas methods on them. Are you just using the canvas as a background?

Comment: @Сергей Кох `create_window` indeed seems to be the way to go. My demo code now works

Comment: @BryanOakley The intention is to create a scrollable area, which seems more difficult than it should. I only use a canvas because it's apparently not possible to scroll a frame

Answer (score 0):

The canvas changes size because you're using `grid` to put the label inside the canvas. `grid` (and `pack`) is designed to shrink or grow a parent widget to fit its children. There are ways to tell `grid` not to do that, but the real problem is that you shouldn't be using `grid` to begin with.

In a comment to the question you mentioned that you want to create a scrollable area. For items to be scrollable on a canvas, they must be created with a canvas method. In the case of a widget, you need to use `create_window` to add the widget to a canvas. This will make the widget a canvas object, and it will move with other widgets on the canvas when you scroll.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=100, height=100)
canvas.grid()

label = tk.Label(canvas, text="TestLabel")
canvas.create_window(10, 10, window=label, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(height=200)

window.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `create_window()` is indeed the solution. Please note that I do not use `pack()` in my demo code

Comment: @Solo: I appreciate you calling that to my attention. I've edited my answer to address `grid` rather than `pack`. I apologize for the confusing mistake.